# Feed subscription statistics with Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, feedburner

I have a Drupal website, and I am currently using Feedburner, mainly to get statistics about the number of subscribers and methods of subscriptions.

However "burning" my feed is complicated, it's hard to restrict people from accessing the original feed, and it only does one feed, as opposed to various tag feeds, user feeds, etc.

How would you have Drupal collect and present feed access and subscription satistics?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [the Feedburner module](http://drupal.org/project/feedburner)? It will do redirection from the original feed URL to the FeedBurner feed URL (FeedBurner itself will still have access to the original). You can do it for multiple feeds, though I think you still have to add those manually, which will be cumbersome for all the various tag feeds.

Comment: Thanks. I currently used Feedbuerner module + RSS permissions module, but this is (1) complicated, (2) needs manual configuration for every feed, as you mentioned (3) it seems that some subscribers cheekily access the original feed in spite of my attempts to block it, which ruins my statistics. That's why I wondered if I couldn't find a solution that doesn't involve feedburner at all.